# How do i remove the border of a progress HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar that shows the shows the computed % of uploaded bits of the videos the user selects.

I want these progress bars to not have any border around them. This is what i have right now:

[image]

And i want to remove the ever-so small border around both progress bars. I tried:

```
progress {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

and a few other things that didnt work.

Comment: You're going to have to find the JavaScript that sets the progress bar border and progress ...  No doubt, it is overriding the native CSS.

Comment: @Zak So i just do progress(variable).style.border = 'none' in my render? (im using react)

Comment: Well that would be less proactive than ideal .. Because you're still trying to counter something that is naively happening ..  Why not try to find the *source* of the progress bar, and stymie it there rather than counter something that is happening after the fact?  Also, here really isn't much to go on here, as you have only posted 2 lines of CSS ..

Comment: @Zak If you would test this yourself, you would find that you cannot remove the border from the `<progress>` element normally.  At least, not in Chrome.

Comment: It did not work. Setting the border through javascript did not work.

Comment: Imagine writing an entire REST api that uses special category sorting on upload, real time preview, upload form with real time error handling and getting stumped on HTML and CSS xD

Comment: Have you tried `progress[value] {  -webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none;`?  --  Evidently `border:none;` only works in FF

Comment: That did it! thanks a billion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `<progress>` element, `border:none;` is only supported by Firefox ..  For all other browsers, you'll need the folowing:

```
progress[value] { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
}
```